# Unity: Game Object Changes Material after a time delay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Essentially, I would like to have a Unity game object change materials after a **specified** time delay.

Comment: Have you ever made a cooldown timer or something?

Comment: Use coroutine, async/await or update with appropriate timers/flags. Even googling your exact question title yields some answers :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like this:
x = does not interfere.
Make sure to add a material by right-clicking in the asset-viewer(in a 3D game).
// means comments, you don't have to put this in your code.
Only select the option your game applies.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Unity;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;



Class x: MonoBehaviour{
float timer;
float TimeWanted = x(number);
Color color;


//if your game is 2D:
SpriteRenderer colorMaker;
//if not:
Renderer colorMaker;


void Start(){
//if your game is 2D:
colorMaker = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
color = colorMaker.color;
//if not:
colorMaker = GetComponent<Renderer>();
color = colorMaker.color;

}
void Update(){
timer+=1*Time.deltaTime;
if(timer>=TimeWanted){
color = Color.blue;
timer=0;
}
colorMaker.color = color;

}

}
```

Comment: In the 3d version, Mesh doesn't have a color/field property, you have to change it to something else (or change it to swapping materials, not colors). 'Time' name for a variable is a little unfortunate, and will cause errors when trying to call Time.deltaTime from a UnityEngine namespace. Also, consider formatting this a little bit, it's honestly hard to read.

Comment: Well, I think the Time variable name sugestion was good.